# TOAD: Table or view doesn't exists

Tags: oracle, toad

I am using:

- **TOAD 10.6**
- Oracle **10g database** with **client 11g**

I have a user ABC with some roles granted to it.

Normally it is working fine but when I run:

```sql
SET ROLE NONE
```

after that I am not able to view data  in **schema browser of TOAD**. I am getting error

> Table or view doesn't exists.

Also

```sql
SELECT * FROM ABC.Table1
```

is showing data when I run in sql editor.

Comment: It is because of the `SET ROLE NONE` that you have executed. This makes all the schema objects of any user inaccessible to that user. Grant that user a suitable role and everything should work fine.

Comment: I am working with the same user objects only

Comment: Getting error in schema browser but everything is working fine in SQL editor